# Options for designing a Repository

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am considering how to write a repository for a new project.

I like the idea of a generic repository like this for the basic CRUD operations:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
```

However, I also read that this is against the spirit of DDD.  Therefore as a compromise I was thinking about creating a generic repository and then a few repositories that inherit from it e.g. `CustomerRepository: Repository` etc.  However, I cannot find any documentation to support this idea.

Q1) Is it a reasonable idea to create a base repository?

Also, I am trying to create one repository per aggregate root rather than one repository per entity.  Say I have two classess i.e. Order and OrderItem (Order is the aggresgate root), then:

Q2) Is it reasonable for all the data access for the OrderItem to go in the Order repository (the aggregate root)? i.e. `SELECT * FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderID=@OrderID` (translates to LINQ).

Comment: Just don't do it... repositories are collections of global variables.

Comment: @Frank hileman, what is the alternative to a repository?

Comment: The alternative is to keep a tree of objects (not unlike a repository), but minimum in size, and rooted in the stack (a local variable) or instance field.

Comment: Are you talking about cqrs? Can you post some code or a link as what you say is very vague.

Comment: Isn't the database itself a giant set of global variables? Why would you want more than one instance of, say, a `Customer` object, when there is only one customer record?

Comment: @john Wu.  The data has to be extracted from the database somewhere.  Are you saying don't use a repository?

Comment: No I am saying the argument that "repositories are collections of global variables" is questionable, seeing that the very purpose of the repository is to represent a collection of global variables.

Comment: @JohnWu You are correct, that is the whole point of the repository. Nevertheless, if you design your solution such that you can have more than one "repository" (i.e. smaller collection and not global), it does reduce the similarity to global variables. The other thing I recommend is to reduce mutation of those objects to the minimum. I am only speaking of the types of horrible bugs I have seen when people use global data mutation all over the code.

Comment: @Frank yes I understand but why would you want to do that? Why model global data as instanced? It's global data, so if you change it in one place, you should change it in all places-- if each bit of code has its own copy, they will get out of sync.

Comment: @JohnWu Global mutable data has many problems that I cannot expand on here, but the thing I was stressing was to limit the access to the data as much as possible, as well as the number of places it is modified. Regardless of how the data is persisted, keeping access as local as possible reduces problems.

Comment: @Frank I understand all the reasons to maintain tight scope and avoid static variables. What I am saying here is that the horse has already left the barn; you *already* have static variables, because you have a single user data store. Masking it with instanced variables does not seem to be a fruitful exercise here, and in fact it is harmful since it misaligns the logical with the physical. For example, if your code implements any kind of caching, you want that to be global, not instanced. I do understand the conventional wisdom, but I am challenging it for this scenario.

Comment: @JohnWu the database is not the model nor the physical, it is the persistence of the model. There are some potentially physical objects or processes being modeled. I am speaking from real experience stripping repositories out of existing projects due to the problems they caused. Typically there are references to the repository everywhere, and the typical bug is: modify in location A, test in location B (unrelated).

Comment: @Frank Sounds like you've got some poorly structured code. If the same record needs to be worked on by more than one function, they should have retrieved the domain object from the (static) repository then passed it between functions, rather than re-retrieving it from the repository each time. Or better yet, encapsulate the scattered logic into the domain object.  Eliminating the repository wouldn't be my first choice for refactoring.

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, poorly structured, and objects are not passed around enough. What I am saying though is the same argument people have made against global variables for decades: this type of code is too easy to write when using globally accessible objects. it is not that you are forced to write bad code, but rather that avoiding globally accessible objects enforces some discipline.

Comment: @Frank or it allows you to not deal with the sequential coupling issue that is the true heart of that sort of problem. Anyway, these days I use instanced factories injected as singletons, which is the best of both worlds, I think.

Answer (score 5):

In Domain Driven Design, the repository is the boundary between the application and the domain model.  It's a role interface used by the program to access the aggregate roots (themselves role interfaces, giving you access to specific entry points in your domain model).

As a rule, you want the interface between the application and the domain model to be as explicit as possible, so that you can optimize for each particular use case.

The fundamental problem with generic repository is that, with no information about which state is relevant, you have to produce all of it.

[Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2007/03/06/better-domain-driven-design-implementation/) offers a nice example of creating a repository that informs the implementation of how the state is going to be used.

That said, if you want to use a generic implementation behind the scenes, and introduce specialized implementations only when you know that the benefits out weight the costs... that's perfectly fine.

Udi's essay also raises an interesting point: the explicit interface puts into the code a better description of what is going on, where a generic interface is more *learnable*.

> This may seem like a lot of trouble to go to. It actually isn’t. It’s pretty much just a different way to package the code you already wrote. Yes, there are more interfaces, and probably more classes, but the amount of business logic code is the same. I’ve been able to keep performance high with this design, but increase its maintainability. I measure maintainability as both the amount of time, and number of changes that need to be made by a programmer familiar with the design. Learnability (?) is often called maintainability, but I think that it’s something else. This design may not be as learnable– meaning it would take a given programmer longer to learn this design than the previous one. I submit that the increased maintainability outweighs the increased learnability substantially.

Answer (score 3):

A1) Usually not. Consider a concrete `CustomerRepository`. It might access data in an SQL database, a document database, directly in-memory etc. It might be beneficial to name it after the data store technology it relies on, e.g. `MongoCustomerRepository`. To abstract the concrete data access technology and achieve easier testing, one would create an `ICustomerRepository` which the concrete `CustomerRepository` would implement. Creating an `IRepository` as a base repository interface then would be abstracting an abstraction. Because of this, it wouldn't serve much benefit besides saving a few lines of repeating interface code and could potentially confuse users.

One similar idea is to build a generic base repository which exposes query methods that take in for example a LINQ expression or another form of a query.  Besides abstracting abstractions, these almost always end up being leaky in that one cannot properly abstract away the query language a concrete implementation might use. And one shouldn't, since queries of ORM Frameworks and database drivers are fully featured and will be hidden behind an interface anyway.

A2) Repository interfaces should be aligned according to business use cases. Furthermore, entities and value objects can only have references to objects inside the same aggregate and other aggregate roots. This is so that the aggregate root can ensure consistency and proper validation of business rules inside the aggregate. Therefore, if an `Order` is the root of an aggregate which contains `OrderItem` value objects, it's inappropriate to return `OrderItem`s directly from a repository. Instead, one should return an `Order` that knows how to satisfy use cases involving its `OrderItem`s.